# How can I install and use the Magento Test Framework (without using pear to install phpunit, on Linux Mint 17)

Tags: testing, unit-tests, phpunit, mtaf, taf

I am trying to set up some sort of automated application testing for Magento stores using the MTAF package described at these links: [Guide](http://www.atwix.com/magento/test-automation-framework-howto/), [Docs](https://github.com/magento/taf/blob/master/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf)

These guides tell you to install PHPUnit using pear, [but this method is disabled as of Dec 2014](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method).

I was finally able to get PHPUnit installed using the commands from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442551/884734) and now I can actually check my `phpunit --version`, which is
`PHPUnit 4.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

The error that I am getting stuck at now is this:
`require_once(): Failed opening required 'SymfonyComponents/YAML/sfYaml.php'`

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444599/884734) says that the test framework is wanting to use the Symfony 1 version of the YAML module. I cannot find this old version anywhere, so it made me wonder if there isn't something I'm overlooking.
I have already tried the [Official SVN repo](http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/) but it just times out.

**Edit:** I guess there was some issue with their servers yesterday. Today it is working and I was able to install the necessary YAML module using this command:

`sudo pear install symfony/YAML`

I'm not really sure if this could be considered a "question" anymore, but I feel it is a good reference for others who might want to install the test framework.

Answer (score 0):

These are the commands that I ran to install the dependencies:

PHPUnit:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar  
chmod +x phpunit.phar  
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Symfony YAML module:

```
sudo pear install symfony/YAML
```